# How to compile and run a c++ source file in visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I've searched for an answer to this question, but couldn't seem to find one. I know that we can use task.json files to automate the build process. But I want to use Visual Studio Code to implement algorithms in C++ for competitive programming. I want to be able to compile a program, and run it all in one go, if there aren't any errors. If there are errors, I would like them to be displayed.

Also, visual studio code comes with an integrated terminal, so it would be nice if the program output could be redirected there. 
Also, how can we map a keyboard shortcut to run this task.

I'm using Visual Studio Code 2019 on Windows 10 with the MinGW G++ compiler.

**EDIT**

I've tried Escape0707's answer below, and I tried executing `'Run Code'` with the default key binding of `Ctrl + Alt + N` but I'm getting this error.

[image]

Comment: Hm, how have you missed this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

Comment: That tutorial only describes how to compile my program, not how to compile and run it with a simple shortcut. I want to know how to edit the tasks.json file to achieve this affect.

Comment: The output name should be "a.exe" on Windows. (Windows indicates that a file is an executable with the ".exe" suffix; Linux uses a file system attribute.)

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + B to build, F5 to run in a debugger. Also, perhaps Visual Studio 2019  Community edition might suit you better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Updated method which combines `make` and `vscode-cpptools` debug:

If you don't care about VSCode integrated debugging tools, which will give you the ability to set breakpoints, change variable value during runtime, inspect variable value, and etc, and you want a somewhat easier, simpler, faster, transparent way to invoke the good old command line tools, skip this section and checkout `Code Runner` below.

The default configurations come with VSCode C++ extension are kind of slow for low-end machines. The worst part is that they will always rebuild your executable, and [don't support 'Start Without Debugging'](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1201). Below is a workaround for Linux (and of course remote-WSL).

To address the first issue, you setup `make` (for simple one source file compiling you only need to install make) to build your source codes, and setup the build task in `tasks.json`. To address the second issue, you create another task just to run the built executable after the first task finished:

> Use Intellisense to learn about each properties in configs.

**`tasks.json`**

```json
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "presentation": {
    "clear": true,
    "focus": true,
    "panel": "shared"
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "make active file",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "make",
      "args": ["${fileBasenameNoExtension}.out"],
      "problemMatcher": "$gcc",
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "run active file executable without debuging",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.out",
      "presentation": {
        "clear": false
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "make and run active file without debuging",
      "group": {
        "kind": "test",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "make active file",
        "run active file executable without debuging"
      ],
      "dependsOrder": "sequence"
    }
  ]
}
```

To enable debugging using VSCode in this way, first make sure you added `-g` compile flag to `CXXFLAGS` in `Makefile`.

> For quick information about how to write a `Makefile`, see [this](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/%7Enewhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html), or [this](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/%7Enewhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html), or [this](https://gist.github.com/maxtruxa/4b3929e118914ccef057f8a05c614b0f). Or check this last part of this answer.

Then, create the following `launch.json`:

**`launch.json`**

```json
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "make and debug active file",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.out",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now you can use command palette to try `Task: Run Build Task`, `Task: Run Test Task`, `Debug: Start Debugging`.

---

### Original answer

Please consider [`Code Runner`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner), as it seems faster (for me) than VSCode's built-in debug procedure for practicing with many small C++ code files. I'll describe how I use that extension to satisfy a similar requirement.

1. Make sure you've configured your `PATH` to include `clang++` so you can invoke it from the integrated terminal.

   > You can also use `g++` by substitute `clang++` below with `g++`. I prefer `clang++` as it provides stricter checks for C++ beginners like me.
2. Install the extension.
3. In your VSCode's `settings.json`, consider adding the following entries:

   ```json
   "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
   "code-runner.preserveFocus": false,
   "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
   "code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true
   ```
4. And add the last customization `code-runner.executorMap` to user/workspace setting that describes which command you would like the extension to send to the terminal when current filename's extension meets the specified ones. For example:

   ```json
   "code-runner.executorMap": {
       "cpp": "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bclang++ -std=c++17 $fileName -o a.out && ./a.out"
   },
   ```

   The above setting tells the extension, "When see a `.cpp` file, send 10 <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to terminal (to delete any mistyped characters) and call `clang++ -std=c++17 *filename* -o a.out && ./a.out`.

   > I use this command on my Linux machine, for Windows, try change the filename extension of the output file to `.exe` and invoke it with `.\a.exe` or simply `a.exe`.
5. Finally, map the `Run Code` command to your preferred keybinding in VSCode's Keyboard Shortcuts settings. Mine is to bind it to <kbd>F5</kbd> which is originally bound to `Debug: Continue`.

**Happy coding!**

---

### Update about `make`

Read on to learn how to avoid redundant compiling process and speed up case test by utilizing `GNU make`. I'll do this on Linux and only for C++, since I have not used `make` on Windows or OS X and C++ is the best for ACM.

1. Make sure `make` is installed and in your `PATH`
2. Create a file named `Makefile` (or `makefile`) under the same directory you invoke `make`. (Or in another directory and `make -f /path/to/Makefile`).
3. Redefine compiler options to whatever you like in the `Makefile`, e.g.:

   ```
   CXX = clang++
   CXXFLAGS = -std=c++17 -g -Weverything -Werror
   ```
4. Create auto-target rule for `*.out` in the `Makefile`, i.e.:

   ```
   %.out: %.cpp
       $(LINK.cpp) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
   ```

   > Attention: must use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to indent the second line, not <kbd>Space</kbd>s.
5. Change `code-runner.executorMap` to :

   ```json
   "code-runner.executorMap": {
       "cpp": "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bmake $fileNameWithoutExt.out && ./$fileNameWithoutExt.out"
   ```
6. (Optional) To ignore `*.out` for `git`:

   ```sh
   echo "*.out" >> .gitignore
   ```
7. (Optional) To remove `*.out` in current directory:

   ```sh
   rm *.out
   ```

Now the `Run Code` command will invoke `make` and `make` will only regenerate `.out` file when the corresponding `.cpp` file is newer than the `.out` file, thus allows us to skip compilation and proceed with testing even smoother.

> The `CXXFLAGS` is for C++ compiler options, `CFLAGS` is for C compiler options. You can find other language compiler options and their variable name using `make -p`, Google and [`GNU make` manual#Automatic-Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables).

Comment: where can I find the settings.json file? On this website: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings it says I can find it at: %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json but I can't seem to find the Code folder.

Comment: There is  a`Open Settings (JSON)` button located at the upper-right corner of the `Settings` tab opened by pressing `Ctrl+,`. For the settings.json in step 3, you can also press `Ctrl+Shift+P` and search `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`.

Comment: I only use JSON to describe my customization for easily texting there at Stack Overflow. You can change the corresponding settings directly in the setting tab UI.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but now I'm getting a different error, I've updated my question to show it.

Comment: My example targets my Arch Linux system and the output file of my compiler can be run with `./filename`. On Windows however, you should give the output filename `a.exe`, etc. And run it by calling `.\a.exe` or `a.exe`. I'll edit my answer to notice the OS I used.

Comment: @Rockstar5645 I've updated the answer to utilize `GNU make`. Hope this would help you better.

Answer (score 3):

To Build/run C++ projects in VS code , you manually need to configure `tasks.json` file which is in .vscode folder in workspace folder . To open `tasks.json` , press `ctrl + shift + P` , and type Configure tasks , and press enter, it will take you to `tasks.json`

Here i am providing my `tasks.json` file with some comments to make the file more understandable , It can be used as a reference for configuring `tasks.json` , i hope it will be useful

After configuring `tasks.json` , to compile and run your c++ file , press `ctrl+shift+B` , this is shortcut for running build tools in vscode . Your C++ program will now run on vscode integrated terminal only .
If this presents some issues , then change default terminal to cmd(by default it is powershell in windows) and make sure there aren't any spaces in path to your file .

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",

    "tasks": [

        {
            "label": "build & run",     //It's name of the task , you can have several tasks 
            "type": "shell",    //type can be either 'shell' or 'process' , more details will be given below
            "command": "g++",   
            "args": [
                "-g",   //gnu debugging flag , only necessary if you want to perform debugging on file  
                "${file}",  //${file} gives full path of the file
                "-o",   
                "${workspaceFolder}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}",    //output file name
                "&&",   //to join building and running of the file
                "${workspaceFolder}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",    //defines to which group the task belongs
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {   
                "echo": false,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": true,
                "panel": "shared",
                "clear": false,
                "showReuseMessage": false
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$gcc"
        },

    ]
}
```

All the properties in the `presentation` of `tasks.json` are just used to customize build tasks as per your needs , feel free to change them to what you like best . You can read about presentation properties (and other things) on [vscode tasks documentations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)